# untar gzcon in memory in R

Tags: r

In R, how can I untar a `gzcon` **in memory**?

Background:

I need to perform some operations on a .tar.gz file in memory and it is important that the file never be written to disk. The file is initially downloaded with `curl_fetch_memory` and results in an object similar to the example data below.

If I then do `untar(gzcon(rawConnection(res$content)))` on the object it will write the data in the tarfile to disk, which is undesirable.

Example data (a `.tar.gz` containing a file named `test.txt` with the content `hello world!`):

```
res <- structure(list(url = "sftp://vm@example.com:/test.tar.gz", 
status_code = 0L, headers = raw(0), modified = structure(1479765215L, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), times = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.312, 0.312), .Names = c("redirect", 
"namelookup", "connect", "pretransfer", "starttransfer", 
"total")), content = as.raw(c(0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00, 0xdf, 
0x6c, 0x33, 0x58, 0x00, 0x03, 0xed, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x0a, 0xc2, 
0x50, 0x10, 0xc4, 0xf1, 0xad, 0x73, 0x8a, 0xe7, 0x05, 0x64, 
0x37, 0x79, 0xd9, 0x9c, 0x47, 0x30, 0x90, 0xe2, 0x49, 0x20, 
0x59, 0x3f, 0x8e, 0xaf, 0x22, 0x42, 0x2a, 0x4d, 0x13, 0x44, 
0xf8, 0xff, 0x9a, 0x29, 0x66, 0x8a, 0x89, 0x7e, 0x8e, 0x7d, 
0xdc, 0x42, 0x36, 0xa4, 0x0f, 0xee, 0xf9, 0x99, 0xd6, 0xb5, 
0xba, 0xcc, 0x17, 0x73, 0xb1, 0x46, 0x2d, 0xbb, 0x7b, 0xa3, 
0xad, 0xa8, 0x69, 0xae, 0x3b, 0x49, 0xba, 0xe5, 0xa9, 0xb7, 
0xf3, 0x1c, 0x87, 0x29, 0x25, 0xb9, 0x9c, 0x3e, 0xef, 0xbe, 
0xf5, 0x7f, 0x6a, 0xe8, 0x4b, 0x19, 0xd3, 0x75, 0x9c, 0xca, 
0x71, 0x57, 0x55, 0xbf, 0x7e, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x58, 
0xeb, 0x0e, 0x02, 0xc4, 0x36, 0xca, 0x00, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00
))), .Names = c("url", "status_code", "headers", "modified", 
"times", "content"))
```

Comment: If you know how to do this from a bash console (I don't) then you should be able to read the code from `untar` and figure out how to hack a replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out parsing tarfiles is not that difficult to do. The core loop of `utils:::untar2` is a good starting point for the implementation of an in-memory `untar` tool. Basically, the tarfile has the following structure:

```
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-~
| 512-byte header | file data | 512-byte header | file data |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-~
```

The tar header format is described in more detail in the [GNU manual for tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html), and is composed of some file attributes, magic numbers, and a checksum.

The pseudocode for the in-memory untar tool is straightforward:

```
repeat {
  parse tar header with file attributes
  for each block in file {
    write block to raw connection
  }
  write raw connection and file attributes to file object
  add file to list
}
return list of files
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the `extras = "O"` flag on untar get you closer to what you need?

For example, if I made a file

```
echo "hello world" > afile
tar -cvf afile.tar.gz afile
```

Then I'm able to read it to stdout (which print to R) with

```
untar('afile.tar.gz', compressed = 'gzip', extras = "-O")
```

I'm using GNU Tar 1.29

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. It looks like that flag doesn't do anything with the internal tar version, and it doesn't display to stdout.

Comment: I'm a wee late here, but check out the modification above if you still need it